# Definition of $Sym^2(V)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n\ge 2$ over a field $k$.

If $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, then $\{v_i\otimes v_j\}_{i,j}$ is a basis of $V\otimes V$.

Define a linear map $T$ from $V\otimes V$ to itself as follows: for basis elements, it is defined by $T(v_i\otimes v_j)=v_j\otimes v_i$, and extend linearly to the space $V\otimes V$.

Then $T^2=I$, $T\neq I$, and so $V\otimes V$ has decomposition into eigenspaces of dimension $1$ and $-1$.

These subspaces are denoted by $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)$ and $\mathrm{Alt}^2(V)$.

**Q.** Is there any way to describe the subspace $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)$ independent of basis?

(I am not too much familiar with tensor product, except its definition, universal property, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
{\rm Sym}^2(V)=(V\otimes V)/H
$$
where $H$ is the subspace generated by all the vectors $v\otimes w-w\otimes v$.

When the characteristic of the field is not $2$, ${\rm Sym}^2(V)$ is the image of the endomorphism of $V\otimes V$ given by
$$
v\otimes w\mapsto\frac12(v\otimes w+w\otimes v).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the definition you give is only valid in characteristic not $2$ (as Andrea points out, in general it's a quotient of $V\otimes V$, not a subspace). It's obvious in the definition that if $1=-1$ there is a problem with the eigenspaces.

But assuming the characteristic is not $2$, the way you described it is already independent of any basis. The only time you used a basis is to define $T$, but that's not actually necessary since it satisfies $T(x\otimes y)=y\otimes x$ for any $x,y\in V$.

You also have to univeral property that it represents *symmetric* bilinear maps $V\times V\to W$ for all spaces $W$, in the same way that $V\otimes V$ represents (non necessarily symmetric) bilinear maps $V\times V\to W$.